# full install on an existing dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot

I am trying to avoid any possible complications of an upgrade of 16.04 to 20.04, in other words, I prefer full installs.

Can Ubuntu 20.04 be installed on a dual boot (one disk) system. The disk currently has Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10.

Edit: In case it is not clear, I want Windows 10 to be uneffected. I do not want to put 20.04 along side of 16.04; I want to overwrite 16.04. Data in the 16.04 portion of the file system will be copied to a backup before installing 20.04. There is no privacy concern because the owner of the physical disk will remain the owner of the physical disk after the installation of 20.04. In other words, file system blocks marked empty will be assumed to be empty. I do not remember if this physical disk had Windows 10 installed before 16.04 or if 16.04 was installed before Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, Dual boot is used to refer to many OSes, the one running and any others (not-running; usually another one but can be another two or more).  You can pre-prepare the disk partitioning yourself (what I do for my own systems), or use *install alongside*.

Comment: You have to check that is enough space left in the disk, that is, if you are not removing 16.04.

Comment: Then you have to check if your system is 64bit, Ubuntu 20.04 is only 64bits.

Comment: If data is backup, can install 20.04 over 16.04, or as been said, install beside, if you have enough space.  Backing up is recommended for either case.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I want to clobber 16.04.  Can Ubuntu do this without harming Windows 10.

Comment: @guiverc The disk is already partitioned because it is already dual booting Ubuntu and Windows. I don't want to keep 16.04. I want to keep Windows 10 and install 20.04.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I don't think it matters the word size of Ubuntu because that is probably not an aspect of the disk formatting. I do not recall ever being asked if I want 32 or 64 bit NTFS. Likewise I do not recall ever being asked to choose between 32 and 64 bit ext4.

Comment: @H2ONaCl 64/32 bit is the CPU architecture, not the filesystem type. It's almost safe to say that relatively new hardware will be already 64bits, but there's no harm on checking. Run `lscpu`.

Comment: Replace a system is easier than what I thought you were asking (ie. keeping 16.04 & adding 20.04). Yes easily done (starting fresh if you *format* your partition(s), or without impacting user files (assuming desktop install) via no-format of partition(s)). Me I'd use *Something-else* as I like to specify everything, but it'll work either way, backup first as it's easy to miss options (eg. the format checkbox you *want* or *don't.want* checked)

Comment: @guiverc As far as I know formatting is necessary only if you need privacy. Ubuntu 20.04 overwriting 16.04 does not guarantee privacy if you use some sort of tool to inspect the file system's blocks marked as empty. Since I am not selling the system I am not concerned about privacy and I will respect blocks marked as empty.

Comment: My use of format did not relate to privacy at all; 'format' alters how the install actually occurs (*on existing releases of Ubuntu anyway as I write this*). If you format you get a 'new' system installed without regard for what was there before hand. With format, no record of your prior packages is kept, nor later used post-install to try and re-install them (where available in the new release) allowing your system to return to as close as it was pre-install. It's the 'format' checkbox which decides which install occurs.  (`ubiquity`; it also will cause a new file-system to be created too)

Comment: @guiverc What you described sounds exactly like a file system format. Perhaps the format checkbox causes a process that is exactly a file system format. If the format checkbox is the only way to be without a route back to some aspects of the old system then so be it. They did not have to do it that way because I have no reason to believe that my file system is corrupt. I do not mind overwriting the file system as long as it does not ruin Windows 10.

Comment: The format check box sets a flag, that flag will cause a number of extra steps to be performed, OR a new file-system to be created (`mkfs` or format) and those 'extra' steps are skipped.  I was trying to write about the changes those 'extra' steps that change the install process also toggled by that 'format' flag (extra step before 'mkfs' occurs & extra step post-expand & write of squashfs). The box sets a flag, to me the 'format/mkfs' is the minor bit controlled by that flag & not what I was writing about.  If you're not sure test (I'm assuming `ubiquity` install as you've not said)

Answer (score 0):

Given a dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 system there can be a serious problem upgrading 16.04 with 20.04 via a complete overwrite.

This answer has it that there can be a serious problem in some cases and this answer will describe a failure scenario. If there are success scenarios people can post them as alternative answers. A failure scenario is a useful answer because it will help people avoid problems. The fact that this, the first posted answer, appeared many days after the question was posed means this might be esoteric knowledge and therefore valuable to the community.

I used `Startup Disk Creator` to make a USB Flash drive installer of 20.04 from the ISO file. That program can automatically detect the ISO if it has been downloaded to the `Downloads` directory and it will automatically detect a USB Flash drive. Download the ISO and insert the Flash drive before starting the program.

I booted into the PC architecture setup program UEFI that people like to call BIOS and made it so that the USB Flash drive would be an early-in-sequence boot device. The 20.04 installation offers 4 options which I will describe as `just install 20.04` for lack of a better name, `install 20.04 along side 16.04`, `erase all operating systems and install`, and `something else`. Looking into the `something else` option I was able to see that there were NTFS and ext4 partitions. I did not know how to direct the program so that 20.04 would overwrite the ext4 partitions and the dialog did not offer much guidance so I decided to go back to the menu option `just install 20.04`. Since I want 16.04 to be overwritten this seemed like the right choice.

After the installation the computer booted to a grub prompt. This is very user unfriendly and I considered this to be a failed attempt.

The internet has tutorials on **initially** setting up a dual boot system with Windows installed first and tutorials on **initially** setting up a dual boot system with Ubuntu installed first. It might be harder to find overwrite/upgrade tutorials for the Ubuntu side of such systems. Hopefully this answer serves as a small contribution towards an understanding of how to (or how not to) perpetually maintain a dual boot system with overwrite/upgrades.

Aside: I decided to abandon use of dual boot systems until it is easier to do overwrite/upgrades. Speculative: Another reason to avoid dual boot is that some Microsoft license enforcement checks the hardware on which it was first installed. After failing to upgrade via an overwrite on a dual boot drive I switched to single booting Windows only. I then found that one of my Microsoft licenses is newly invalid. It might be possible to correct this problem but it might not be worth the time and effort. I purchased a new license.